# Domain of a bounded linear operator on a Hilbert Space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

In books, I always that a bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space is defined on all the Hilbert space, while an unbounded linear operator can not be defined on all the Hilbert space.
Nevertheless, I am not able to find a demostration for that.

Specifically, let $\mathcal{H}$ be a complex Hilbert space  and let $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ be a bounded linear operator on $\mathcal{H}$.
I understood that the domain $D(A)$ of $A$ is the set:

$$
D(A):=\left\{\psi\in\mathcal{H}\,: A(\psi)\in\mathcal{H}\right\}
$$
I would like to know how to prove that the fact that $A$ is bounded implies that $D(A)=\mathcal{H}$, and the converse.

Thank You.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't.  There's nothing to prevent you from defining a bounded linear operator on a proper subspace.  There are also unbounded linear operators defined on the whole space (although you won't find explicit examples of this, because it requires some form of the Axiom of Choice).

However, a **closed** linear operator  defined on the whole space is bounded (Closed Graph Theorem), and a **closed** linear operator that is bounded must have a closed domain.

EDIT: Here's the proof of this last statement.  Suppose $x$ is in the closure of $\mathcal D(A)$ for a bounded closed operator $A$.  Thus there is a sequence 
$x_n$ in $\mathcal D(A)$ with limit $x$.  Since $A$ is bounded, $A x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence.  A Hilbert space is complete, so $A x_n$ has a limit $y$.
Thus the sequence of pairs $(x_n, A x_n)$ converges to $(x, y)$ in $\mathcal H \times \mathcal H$.  But since $A$ is closed, i.e. its graph is closed, 
$(x,y)$ must be in the graph of $A$, which says $x \in \mathcal D(A)$.

Comment: Thank You. One last thing: is there a reference where I can find a detailed treatment of domains of operators?

Comment: I am also looking for some proof that a closed linear, bounded operator has a closed domain and if so, is the domain the entire space?

Comment: In your edit you say $A$ is closed so its graph is closed.  But wouldn't this imply that the operator is continuous?  Continuity = closed graph, but closed operator $\neq$ closed graph.

Comment: The definition is: a closed operator is an operator whose graph is closed.  There are lots of closed unbounded operators.  The Closed Graph Theorem says their domains are not the whole space.

Comment: So, a bounded operator defined on the whole Hilbert space is closed; a bounded and closed operator must have a closed domain. Now, can a bounded operator $A$ with $\mathcal{D}(A)\subset\mathcal{H}$ have a non-closed domain?

Comment: Of course.  Just start with a bounded operator on the whole space and restrict its domain.

Comment: then, restricting a bounded operator on a non-closed domain, do I get a non-closed operator?

Comment: Yes, of course.